# terminal window freeze for a few seconds after typing

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, freeze

In the terminal window, sometimes after pressing a key the windows "freezes" for a few seconds. I can continue typing afterwards, but after a few seconds-minute it happens again.

The freeze happens ONLY after I type.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity+compiz (don't know if it is related, because it didn't happen right after the installation of the OS).
Also running on VMWare.

```
output of "lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3"

00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VMware SVGA II Adapter [15ad:0405]
        Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter [15ad:0405]
        Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
        Kernel modules: vmwgfx
    00:10.0 SCSI storage controller [0100]: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI [1000:0030] (rev 01)
```

Update:

**Happens only in Unity Desktop + comiz is disabled**

Thanks!

Comment: what does the journal say around the time of the incident? I would try running `jouralctl -f` and check what it says when the window freezes

Comment: @justinbenge - compiz[2222]: context mismatch in svga_sampler_view_destroy

Comment: @TCS I think (I have been wrong before though...) that `context mismatch....` is due to the use of video acceleration, you may try disabling it to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: @justinbenge - that worked! write an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compiz[2222]: context mismatch` is due to a use of video acceleration, so usually disabling it should fix the problem :)